# Does spring mvc have the concept of before/after controller action events?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Does spring mvc have the concept of events firing before/after a controller action?

I am currently using a filter, but I could also inherit from a basecontroller for specific sections of my website and use before/after events if they exist.

So I mean I can create an event that fires just before a controller's action fires, or an event that fires after.

Comment: What's wrong with the filter?

Comment: @skaffman I'm used to using events, curious if they existed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for interceptors. I don't know what strategy you are using for routing you requests to your controller methods, so I assume you are using annotations. Then, here is how you could put your interceptor on the stack:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
        </list>
      </property>
</bean
```

Where *loginInterceptor* is the id of a bean declared in your application context which implements the interface *org.springframework.validation.Validator*

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something you can achieve using [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html).